# What is the cleanest way to save and load multiple DOM elements as JSON with the FileSystem(fs) Module from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jquery-ui, dom

I need to save dynamically added DOM elements(draggable DIVs) to a file and load them at a later time.
What is the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save mySql or Mongodb

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'locahost',
    user     : 'foo',
    password : 'bar',
    database : 'test'
});

// the callback inside connect is called when the connection is good
connection.connect(function(err){
    var sql = "select 'Joe' as name from dual";

    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        //  you need to end your connection inside here.
        connection.end();
        console.log(rows[0].name);
    });
});
```

Comment: I already know how I will save the file(Node.js File System Module). I want to know how to convert dynamically added DOM elements to JSON and back. Thanks for taking your time